# The method 'concat' isn't defined for the type 'Stream', help merging 2 snapshots

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot> dataStream(String userUid) {
  return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>((ref) {
    final snapshot1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('catégorie')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: userUid)
        .snapshots();
    final snapshot2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('catégorie')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: 'default')
        .snapshots();
    return snapshot1.concat(snapshot2);
  });
}
```

i want to concatenate snapshot1 and 2, but i have this error "The method 'concat' isn't defined for the type 'Stream'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'concat'"

i tried replacing 'concat' with 'merge', still the same error, i also tried replacing it with 'concatenate', 'mergeWith' but still same problem. Please for help

Comment: `concat()` is a stand alone function that takes two `Stream<>`s and returns a new one.

Comment: i took it from bing conversation, please can you help me concatenate the 2 snapshots?